# Incorrect Date Exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception, datetime

I am trying to enter a date with year 1900 using java into sql, but I am getting exception as :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Can you post some code? We dont have a lot to work with there...

Comment: What code are you using to enter that date?

Comment: What is the type of your column ? A DateTime or a TimeStamp ?

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **TIMESTAMP** to store the dates the minimal value is '**1970-01-01 00:00:01**'.

Use **DATE** to store older dates or **DATETIME** to store older dates with time.

Check the MySQL documentation about the date format http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: I was also having same issue and it was due to reason you have mentioned. Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: After 11 years this answer keeps saving a lot of time. Thanks!