# Not able to persist date below year 1970 in mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

I am using spring with MySQL DB. When I want to store date after 1969 it's fine , but below 1970 it's throwing error. The error is 
' com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1906-09-16 00:00:00' for column 'DATEOFBIRTH' at row 1.'

My domain has the field,

```
@Column(name = "DATEOFBIRTH", nullable = true, length = 20)
@Setter
@Getter
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

I am using mysql connector jar version 5.1.30. I need some suggestions.

Comment: May be this can help :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466425/incorrect-date-exception

Comment: @Apollo : We can use data also it's mentioned in one solution in the link that you have provided,

Comment: You can if you do need need time along with date.

Answer (score 2):

Check the data type of the column you are using. It should be DATETIME to save dates in range '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

TIMESTAMP supports range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Here is the documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: I am using date only right. It's not a timestamp so it should accept below 1970 also right?

Comment: Let me make it clear. The data type of the column in MySql must be of DATETIME not in the entity. Try desc <table-name> to know the column type. In entity any of the DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, DATE can be read through Date data type.

Comment: Understood uday. cool